# Longest palindrome program

Tags: java

I am going through this [longest palindrome program](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/12/leetcode-solution-of-longest-palindromic-substring-java/):

```
   public static String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        if(s==null || s.length()<=1)
            return s;

        int len = s.length();
        int maxLen = 1;
        boolean [][] dp = new boolean[len][len];

        String longest = null;
        for(int k=0; k<s.length(); k++){
            for(int i=0; i<len-k; i++){
                int j = i+k;
                if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j) && (j-i<=2||dp[i+1][j-1])){
                    dp[i][j]=true;

                    if(j-i+1>maxLen){
                       maxLen = j-i+1; 
                       longest = s.substring(i, j+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return longest;
    }
```

I ran this program in debug mode in my eclipse multiple times, but it is not clear for me how this program is able to get the longest palidrome value.

How the boolean array is used, how the variable `j` is used, mainly what is the use of this condition `j-i<=2||dp[i+1][j-1]`

The link says the space complexity is `O(n^2)`, which part of the program indicates this space complexity.

Comment: "which part of the program indicates this space complexity." - well, since it says _space_ complexity it's probably `new boolean[len][len]`, i.e. a 2D array of `n * n` elements. Additionally, since there are 2 nested loops that operate on the same `n` (string length) there's also at least a `O(n^2)` _time_ complexity.

Comment: I believe the O(n^2) is because of the nested iterations

Comment: the space complexity is O(n^2) because the program needs the length of the string squared objects for calculation "new boolean[len][len];". It also has time complexity of O(n^2) because there are two nested for-loops, where the first one iterates over the length of the string and the second over length-k or at average length/2. the time complexity is something of n*(n/2) but the O-Notation just cares about the highest value in the complexity which is O(n^2)

Comment: Idid not put too much thought into this but it seems to me that the code does a double n loop -> n^2 complexity. How it seeks the longest palindrome ? It creates a table of booleans, each element of the table indicates if the (i,j) substring is still a palindrome. Longest palindrome is the palindrome found for the highest i-j difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Dynamic Program approach. Where you start from one letter string (which is a palindrome by default) and gradually increase the number of letters in a string.

For that they are using two dimensional array,

```
    /*
 *      B  A  N  A  N  A
 *     ------------------
 *  B | T  F  F  F  F  F
 *  A |    T  F  T  F  T
 *  N |       T  F  T  F
 *  A |          T  F  T 
 *  N |             T  F
 *  A |                T
 * */
```

thus space complexity n^2.

For any [i][j] cell you need to check [i+1][j-1] cell in order to find out that whether the substring before adding this letter was palindrome or not.

Below link has a very articulate video It is using similar approach.
http://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/longest-palindromic-substring

Comment: Thanks for the video link. I am not clear on the last part, how it is confirmed that `ANANA` is palindrome in the video. Because at that particular point `i=1` and `j=5` so array element will be p[2][4], there is no entry at this position. Can you please explain that part of it.

Comment: Here at any point let's say (1,4) represents sub-string "ANAN". i represents starting letter (vertically, 'A') and j represents end letter (horizontally, 'N'). And we are traversing diagonally. first we are taking substring of two letters then 3 then 4 and then 5. thus when you reach (1,5) just previous for loop would've covered [(0,1),(1,4),(2,5)] and for loop before that would've covered [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)] thus (2,4) is ready when you reach (1,5). I hope i'm able to explain it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear now. Thanks for sharing the wonderful video.

Answer (score 0):

## Find out the longest Palindrome in a string using Javascript

#### Optimal Solution

```
const lpal = str => {
  let lpal = ""; // to store longest palindrome encountered
  let pal = ""; // to store new palindromes found
  let left; // to iterate through left side indices of the character considered to be center of palindrome
  let right; // to iterate through left side indices of the character considered to be center of palindrome
  let j; // to iterate through all characters and considering each to be center of palindrome
  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) { // run through all characters considering them center of palindrome
    pal = str[i]; // initializing current palindrome
    j = i; // setting j as index at the center of palindorme
    left = j-1; // taking left index of j
    right = j+1; // taking right index of j
    while (str[j] === str[right]) { // while right elementis same as center element
      pal = pal + str[right]; // then add right to pal
      right++; // increase right by one
    }
    while (left >= 0 && right < str.length) { // while left and right indices exist
      if(str[left] === str[right]) { // if left value is equal to right value
        pal = str[left] + pal + str[right]; // add in front and back of pal
      } else { // if left value is NOT equal to right value
        break; // break out of while
      }
      left--; // move left index by one
      right++; // move right index by one
    }
    if(pal.length > lpal.length) { // if this pal longer than longest pal 
      lpal = pal; // set longest pal to be this pal
    }
  }
  return lpal; // return longest pal
}
```

#### Fairly optimal solution

```
const longestPalindrome = str => {
  let isPalindrome = false;
  let test;
  for (let i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= str.length - i; j++) {
      isPalindrome = true;
      test = str.slice(j, j+i);
      for (let k = 0; k < Math.floor(test.length/2); k++) {
        if (test[k] !== test[test.length-1-k]) {
          isPalindrome = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (isPalindrome) {
        return test;
      }
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

#### Brute force sort of solution

```
const longestPalindrome1 = str => {
  let longestPalindrome = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = str.length ; j > i; j--) {
      const test = str.slice(i,j);
      let isPalindrome = true;
      for (let k = 0; k < test.length/2; k++) {
        if (test[k] !== test[test.length - 1 - k]) {
          isPalindrome = false;
        }
      }
      if (isPalindrome && test.length > longestPalindrome.length) {
        longestPalindrome = test;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return longestPalindrome;
}
```

#### Recursive Solution

```
const longestPalindrome2 = str => {
  if (str.length > 1){
    let [palindrome1, palindrome2] = [str, str];
    for (let i=0;i<Math.floor(str.length/2);i++) {
      if(str[i]!==str[str.length-i-1]) {
        palindrome1 = longestPalindrome(str.slice(0, str.length-1));
        palindrome2 = longestPalindrome(str.slice(1, str.length));
        break;
      }
    }
    return palindrome2.length > palindrome1.length ? palindrome2 : palindrome1;
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
```

#### Example Input

```
console.log(longestPalindrome2("babababababababababababa"));
console.log(longestPalindrome1("babababababababababababa"));
console.log(longestPalindrome("babababababababababababa"));
console.log(lpal("babababababababababababa"));
```

#### Output

```
bababababababababababab
bababababababababababab
bababababababababababab
bababababababababababab
```

Try these solutions on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution to find longest palindromic substring**

```js
let userInput = "FRACECARID";
let reversedString, originalString, longestPalindrome;
let palindromeArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < userInput.length - 1; i++){
    for(let j = i + 2; j < userInput.length + 1; j++){
        originalString = userInput.substring(i, j);
        reversedString = originalString.split("").reverse().join("");
        if(originalString == reversedString){
            palindromeArray.push({x: originalString.length, y: originalString});
        }
    }
}
palindromeArray.sort(compareX); //sorting in descending order based on length of the palindrome
longestPalindrome = palindromeArray[0].y;
console.log("Longest Palindrome: ", longestPalindrome);
function compareX(a, b){
    return b.x - a.x;
}
```